# Is it possible to optimize the pymongo cursor to close the connection and continue where it's finished?

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, pymongo

We use `MongoDB:4.12.14` in our project its collection, Buzz contains more than ~3m records. The object is too complex to write here, but We run a query for `X:<str>` and `Y:<datetime>` fields which look like this:

`{X: <str>, Y: {$gte: <datetime>, $lte: <datetime>}}`

There is index for that query > `{X: 1, Y: 1}`

Our problem is We use MongoDB via `pymongo:3.12` and over TLS, but the query runs more than 1 minute despite there is index on the collection. After `pymongo` returns a cursor, We call `list` to exhaust the cursor and retrieve all records, but after it reaches the TLS timeout threshold it comes back with that > `socket.timeout: The read operation timed out` and it comes from

- `pymongo/pool.py:751`
- `pymongo/network.py:200`
- `pymongo/network.py:291`
- `python3.7/ssl.py:1071`
- `python3.7/ssl.py:929`

My question is what should we do with that now? What could be the next step? Is it possible somehow to close the connection and continue where it finished? Would it be the proper way at all?

Thanks for your attention in advance.

Comment: Is your `client.options.pool_options.socket_timeout` set to `None`?

Comment: as I see it's not available at `pymongo:3.12`

Comment: `pymongo`'s changelog shows that `socketTimeoutMS` was added in version 3.0.  If you set it to `None`, do you notice any differences?

Comment: You are right, there is option for that, and maybe it solves our issue, but I'm afraid of not seeking that solution. My problem is with it, If I turn off the socket timeout, then the service will get stuck in an idle state and will hold the database unnecessarily.